# How to mutate the cache while using the API with query parameters using useSWRInfinite hook

Tags: reactjs, swr, mutate

I am using the useSWRInfinite hook for data fetching in my React app. To update the cache, I use the "mutate" feature, which works fine with a URL without parameters. However, when using the URL with query parameters, global mutations do not work. Does anybody have any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bound mutate, it's easy to mutate the cache. But sometimes we need to use global mutation. I haven't found a better way to mutate the cache of the end point with query parameters while using global mutate. I read the documentation for SWR and found the following way to update the cache directly. Here I set cache to undefined so that the API will hit and update the cache too.

```
import { useSWRConfig } from 'swr'

const {mutate,cache}=useSWRConfig()

const matchMutate=()=>{
   return (matcher) => {if (!(cache instanceof Map))         
  {throw new Error('matchMutate requires the cache provider to be a Map instance') }
   const keys = []
   for (const key of cache.keys()) {
  if (key.includes(matcher))   //here you can use endsWith, startsWith to match cache key
     {
     keys.push(key)
     }
    }

const mutations = keys.map((key) => mutate(()=>key, undefined,{revalidate:false}))
return Promise.all(mutations)
}}
```

You can call matchMutate() where you need it and pass the end point that you need to mutate.

For example

```
matchMutate('/api/job/job/?offset=0&limit=10&search=teacher')
```